# A word for retroactive, but in a sci-fi way

Tags: word-request

https://www.thefreedictionary.com/retroactively

Adv.    1.  retroactively - after the fact; "he will get paid retroactively"

How to use retroactively in a sci-fi way?

> The space-time police retroactively punished the criminals by
> traveling back in time and punishing them.

But it means after the fact with the effects being carried over, but it doesn't mean go back in time, is there a word for this, because it doesn't seem to fit the meaning I want to assign it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use the word [preemptively](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/preemptively) in this situation

> as a measure taken against something anticipated or feared.

So your sentence could be

> The space-time police *preemptively* punished the criminals by traveling back in time and punishing them.

This is different than *retroactive* because the crime has presumably not taken place yet. What the purpose of this punishment is, given that no crime has yet been committed, is a different matter, and is just one of the many issues with time-travel.